# Inkscape: Flow into frame makes text disapear

Tags: inkscape

When I do a "Text" -> "Flow into frame" the text sometimes disappears, or is partially deleted.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Your text must be smaller than the text box and contain spaces. Additionally, a file can become... corrupt?

When doing "Text" -> "Flow into frame" if the text contains a string of characters unbroken by a space and longer than a horizontal line of the area you are flowing into, that entire character string and all characters after it will be deleted. If this happens to be the first word, it will also prevent you from typing further characters.

This also happens vertically. All text that extends further vertically down than the space you are flowing into will be deleted. If there is not enough vertical space for one line then it will delete all text and prevent you from typing further characters.

I haven't determined how it works, but a single file can also become "corrupt" where "flow into frame" wont work at all, even when the same action will work in other Inkscape files.

On Inkscape 0.92.4, Windows 10 build 17763

Comment: This feature should have been better named to something that actually describes what it does. "Flow into frame" is downright misleading. If things will be deleted, there should at least be a message explaining why or a warning saying that the text needed to be smaller. Or better yet, fix the (what I believe is a) bug and scale the text to the largest size that will allow all text to be visible!! not sure why after all these years these "features" still don't exist. *and the documentation OH THE HORROR*

Answer (score 0):

Note that in my case the text had not actually disappeared! I am also on 0.9.2 and whenever I use "Flow Into Frame" on a complicated path or cut a path with text in it the text vanishes, but it is just a rendering glitch!

I made the text appear inside the frame again after cutting it with other paths by moving the frame slightly. Perhaps a better trick is to rotate the frame while pressing **ctrl** and then rotate back. This is because them you could easily undo any actual transformation without using the **ctrl + z** undo combination, which will undo the text showing up again too.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem and found out that **baseline spacing** was the reason. If set to 0, the text disappears. Once I changed that value, the **Flow to Frame** option worked.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem with that, then I tried to re-install the inkscape 1.01 which has file extension of *.msi (not *.exe). Not bad, it could work. Just try this way...